# adding data to a axios request

Tags: axios, vuejs3

I have a static AxiosInstance with the baseUrl set. It works fine but when I want to add a body I am not able to.

Example:

```
const grpcClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: url.baseUrl,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    //params: {base64_encoded: 'true', fields: 'stdout'},
});

export const api = {

    async getTest() {
       async getTest() {
    try{
        return await grpcClient.get<BlogResponse>("/v1/get", {data: {'blogId': '2108'}})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                return res.data
            })
    }catch (err) {
        console.log("error" + err);
    }
},

}
```

This results in a 500 error.

How can I submit the body with axios when I have the AxiosInstance already defined?

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet is working fine.

First you need to import `const qs=require('querystring')` and then

```
        let {
                data
            } = await axiosClient.get(`v1/get?${qs.stringify({
            blogId:2018
        })}`).then(response => {
                return response;
            }).catch(error => {
                return 'Something Went Wrong!';
            });
```

Comment: require is not a good idea. This is what worked, thank you very much.... `import qs from 'query-string';` and `yarn add query-string` ... update your answer and I will accept.